# Remover acentos y apóstrofes de una cadena

Tags: vb.net, regex

Estoy buscando solo remover acentos y apostrofes de una cadena usando regex pero también me esta removiendo los dos puntos `:` y caracteres como `$`, `%` y eso no es lo quiero:

```
Dim palabra2 As String = "ref:0001.24 $45.23 costo' de producción"
Dim mailgurdado As String = Regex.Replace(palabra2.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), "[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+", "")
```

esto me devuelve:

> ref000124 4523 costo de produccion

yo busco que me regrese:

> ref:0001.24 $45.23 costo de produccion

Comment: Ya casi la tienes. Es sólo añadir dentro de tu regex, los caracteres que quieres preservar además de los alfanuméricos y el espacio

Comment: ok los agregare y te comento

Comment: era correcto, agregue al regex lo que queria mantener y listo.

Comment: Puedes ahora añadir tu solución completa (incluyendo una descripción breve y el fragmento de código relevante) como respuesta a tu pregunta y luego puedes marcarla como aceptada :)  Así todos sabrán cómo resolver este mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

El `^` al inicio de `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` significa '*que no sea*' uno de esos caracteres. Entonces, cualquier caracter que no sea `a-zA-Z0-9`  se va a reemplazar (eliminándolo).

Hay 2 opciones:

1. Agregar todas las excepciones que quieras, por ejemplo los que ya identificaste: `"[^a-zA-z0-9:$% ]+"`
2. Eliminar solamente tildes (U+0301) y apóstrofes `'` (sin negar la clase de caracteres):

   ```
   ['\u0301]+
   ```

**Código**

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

---

```
Dim palabra2 As String = "ref:0001.24 $45.23 costo' de producción"
Dim mailguardado As String

mailguardado = Regex.Replace(palabra2.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), "['\u0301]+", "")

' ---> mailguardado = "ref:0001.24 $45.23 costo de produccion"
```

---

**Otros** que te pueden interesar: acento grave `\u0300`, circunflejo `\u0302`, virgulilla `\u0303`, diéresis `\u0308`, entre [otros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks).